# comparing strings when 1 string contains part of the other string

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I am using the following code to compare packetbuffer to a string,

```
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];
!strcmp(packetBuffer, "turn on light")
```

however how could I use to compare it to a string should packetbuffer = testing1234 and the string to be compared to equal "testing", with out the last 4 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr):

```
if (strstr(packetBuffer, "testing") != NULL)
{
    // packetBuffer contains "testing"
    // so do something...
}
```

Note: if you need to test for the substring just at the start of the string then you can do it like this:

```
if (strstr(packetBuffer, "testing") == packetBuffer)
{
    // packetBuffer starts with "testing"
    // so do something...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem good because it become true if `packetBuffer` is `XXtestingXX`, which is not `testing(some 4 digits)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT: it's not clear that the OP requires the substring to be at the start of the buffer, but I've updated the answer to cover this possibility anyway.

Comment: The second should be `strstr(packetBuffer, "testing") == packetBuffer`, not `!=`.

Comment: @MikeCAT: thanks for catching that copy-paste bug - fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use standard C library, `strncmp` is useful.
The length is also checked to make sure there are exactly 4 characters (not just digits) after "testing".

```
if (strlen(packetBuffer) == 11 && strncmp(packetBuffer, "testing", 7) == 0) {
    // they are equal
}
```

Note that this is not very good code since some magic numbers are used.